# Splitting filename and creating additional coloumn in the data frame to add the information from name

Tags: r

I am reading a dataset with the following code from the directory:

```
df= read.csv('101_E424690_N566610.csv',  skip = 6)
```

then changing the names:

```
         colnames(df) = c("type","date","v1","v2","v3","v4","v5","v6","v7","v8","v9","v10","v11","v12","v13","v14","v15","v16","v17","v18","v19","v20","v21","v22","v23","v24","total")
```

I am trying to split the file name as it has the ID number, easting and northing and add 3 additional coloumn after "Type" and "data" coloumn before starting "V1", "V2" etc., I have got some code but I think what I am doing is not right, the codes I am trying is:

```
split <- strsplit(df,"_") 
     gsub('df', '', lapply(split, '[', 2))
```

What I am trying to get is to create 3 additional coloumn and paste ID = 101, Easting = 424690, and Northing = 566610.

is this possible with R?

Many thanks,
Ayan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ayan, remember to give reproducible examples. One solution to have your columns after the date column:

```
df=data.frame(type="T",date="D",v=rnorm(10),total=1:10)
s = strsplit("101_E424690_N566610","_",fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
cbind(df[,c("type","date")],ID=s[1],Easting=s[2],Northing=s[3],df[,3:ncol(df)])

   type date  ID Easting Northing         v total
1     T    D 101 E424690  N566610  0.136314     1
2     T    D 101 E424690  N566610 -0.696407     2
3     T    D 101 E424690  N566610  0.057647     3
4     T    D 101 E424690  N566610  0.110771     4
5     T    D 101 E424690  N566610  0.397276     5
6     T    D 101 E424690  N566610 -0.440799     6
7     T    D 101 E424690  N566610  0.909284     7
8     T    D 101 E424690  N566610  0.007315     8
9     T    D 101 E424690  N566610  0.407037     9
10    T    D 101 E424690  N566610 -0.337159    10
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, this works as well, really appreciate for your help, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the ID, easting, and northing information from your filename and add it to the dataframe?

try this:

```
filename <- '101_E424690_N566610.csv'
df <- read.csv(filename,  skip = 6)
colnames(df) <- ...
d <- strsplit(filename,"_")
d$ID <- d[[1]][1]
d$east <- d[[1]][2]
d$north <- d[[1]][3]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you very much for your answer, I relay appreciate your help! Thanks again